# C: ether_aton return type

Tags: c, return-type

I was wondering what the return type of the `ether_aton()` function is?

From the Linux Man Page:

> `ether_aton()` converts the 48-bit Ethernet host address asc from the
>          standard hex-digits-and-colons notation into binary data in network
>          byte order and returns a pointer to it in a statically allocated
>          buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.  `ether_aton()` returns
>          NULL if the address is invalid."

Comment: `struct ether_addr *` it's there, no?

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ether_aton.3.html) itself

> `struct ether_addr *ether_aton(const char *asc);`